# How to style the Calendar icon in a date input?

Tags: html, css, forms, styling, pseudo-element

i have styled the input[type=date]

```
<div class="field">
                    <label  class="label"> Check in</label>
                    <input type="date" class="input" >
                </div><br>
                <div class="field">
                    <label  class="label"> Check out</label>
                    <input type="date" class="input" >
                </div><br>
```

```
.input{
        float: right;
        height: 1.8vw;
        width: 10vw;
        border: 1px solid #FCA311;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

due to this the calendar icon is not visible, how should i style the icon. I want the icon to be yellow color to match the theme

I tried using :before pseudo element , but it didn't do anything
I want the code to support every browser

```
input[type=date]:before {
  content: '\1F4C5'; 
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator` on the `input` element to accomplish this.

Works on Chrome, Safari and most webkit-based browsers

```css
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
It worked, not like what i wanted but its a lot better than before